# What does Grub error "no such device: /.disk/info" mean, and how to fix it?

Tags: grub2

I have installed Debian Testing with KDE Plasma DE, and I think this happened after a while, when I had a Grub problem which I fixed using a live USB, chrooting and re-installing grub.

There's no booting problem other than these two error messages that appear on black screen immediately before the grub menu:

```
error: no such device: /.disk/info
error: no such device: /.disk/mini-info
```

I wonder if this indicates a problem that should be taken care of, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Debian 12 (and newer, apparently), when installed on a Secure Boot-enabled UEFI system, the `/boot/grub/grubx64.efi` includes a *memdisk image* (approximately 2.4M in size) which contains an Unicode font and a mini `grub.cfg` file, with the following contents:

```
if [ -z "$prefix" -o ! -e "$prefix" ]; then
        if ! search --file --set=root /.disk/info; then
                search --file --set=root /.disk/mini-info
        set prefix=($root)/boot/grub
if [ -e $prefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg ]; then
        source $prefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg
elif [ -e $prefix/grub.cfg ]; then
        source $prefix/grub.cfg
else
        source $cmdpath/grub.cfg
```

It also includes an *embedded configuration file* which says simply:

```
normal (memdisk)/grub.cfg
```

The built-in default value for `$prefix` is set to `/EFI/debian`.

So, when `grubx64.efi` begins executing, it will first use the configuration file within the memdisk image.

First, that configuration file checks if `$prefix` is undefined or there is no matching file or directory on the ESP partition. If so, it will set GRUB's initial `$root` to whatever partition/filesystem that contains either `/.disk/info` or `/.disk/mini-info`, and sets `$prefix` to point to `/boot/grub` on that filesystem.

I guess these files would exist on Debian installation media, and this is how Debian can have just one signed reproducible binary build cover all their needs for Secure Boot-compliant bootloader.

It seems to me that with a permanently installed OS, it should work like this:

1. The built-in default `$prefix` is `/EFI/debian`, which is a directory which should exist on the ESP.
2. The embedded configuration tells GRUB to follow the memdisk-based configuration first. The default root filesystem for GRUB will be the ESP.
3. Since `$prefix` is set and the directory exists on the ESP, the first `if` ... `then` condition will not be true, and the `search` commands should be skipped.
4. `/EFI/debian/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg` does not exist on the ESP (it would exist on the Debian installation media), so the second `if` ... `then` condition will not be true either.
5. There should be a `/EFI/debian/grub.cfg` on the ESP (`/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg` when the OS is running normally) telling where the real GRUB configuration is located. So the `elif` condition will be true and GRUB will read the file. If you have a dedicated `/boot` partition, it could contain something like this:

```
search.fs_uuid 12345678-90ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

This would select your `/boot` filesystem by UUID for GRUB's root filesystem (= the filesystem all subsequent paths accessed by GRUB refer to), and then use it to read the actual GRUB configuration in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

If your `/boot` is in a different location, like on an encrypted volume, or just a regular directory on your root filesystem, then the contents of your `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg` would be different to suit your circumstances.

In your case, something goes wrong in the first `if` ... `then` condition within the memdisk configuration: maybe your active `grubx64.efi` is not located in the ESP's `/EFI/debian` directory (`/boot/efi/EFI/debian/` when accessing it from a booted-up OS)? Or maybe your firmware interprets pathnames case-sensitively and the actual character case of the directory names is different?

Anyway, it ends up searching for `/.disk/info` and `/.disk/mini-info` which should exist on installation media only, and those failing searches cause the error messages you're seeing.

Since GRUB is working otherwise, the messages could most likely be harmless and only a minor cosmetic annoyance. But if you wish to get rid of them, you should use `efibootmgr -v` to review the boot paths in the UEFI boot variables and all the pathnames referenced by GRUB on the way to your real GRUB configuration file (as explained above), and correct any discrepancies as you find them.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems this was caused by me when I decided to change the name my distro (manually editing some system files like "/etc/lsb-release" and "/etc/osb-release") from Debian to Kdebian. Apparently, it's causing some confusion during re-installation of grub, and in order to get rid of this minor cosmetic error, I should  either (1) probably edit one or two more system files, or (2) change the subdir name from kdebian to debian, and also manually change that efi boot entry accordingly, or (3) go back to the original distro name, Debian...

Comment: It seems this also explains why KDE neon installation results in two EFI subdirs: neon and ubuntu, and maybe I should also create a second subdir named "debian" like that. I would expect KDE neon developers to find a better workaround. If they they couldn't, I shouldn't dare to try with my elementary skills of computing instead of following their lead. ;-)

Comment: It depends on if you have Secure Boot enabled or not, and if you do, how far you wish to go: using the `debian` subdirectory is probably the easiest way, creating a customized `grubx64.efi` signed with a previously-enrolled MOK would probably be the middle ground, and taking over the control of your firmware Secure Boot keys and signing everything with your own custom keys might be the hardcore way (extra points if there is no user interface for manipulating the firmware keys ;-).

Comment: Thanks, I've taken the easiest way as KDE neon developers, and it worked. :-)
Perhaps I should also add this as a "secondary answer" for adventurer noobs like me changing the distro name in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this problem came about as a result of a “semi-finished” work of changing the distro name from **Debian** to **Kdebian** by manually editing a couple of system files. And, thanks to the Accepted Answer above, I could fix it by creating a subdirectory named `debian` under `EFI` (in addition to the `kdebian` subdirectory), containing a `grub.cfg` file with the following contents only:

```
search.fs_uuid 6d4c4d33-240f-4577-9282-c3862db81a30 root hd0,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

(Values `6d4c4d33-240f-4577-9282-c3862db81a30` and `hd0,gpt3` subject to change according to each system)